# Programmatically save chrome's console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging

Is there a way in javascript or nodejs to programmatically get everything in chrome's console so I can save it to a file or database?

Answer (score 0):

Another method to get everything in the Chrome console is to use http://www.consoleexport.com
You enter your URL and submit. It will display all console entries in a table which you can copy and paste into a spreadsheet. Or you can choose to export the console entries to a .txt (tab separated) or .xlsx format file.

Answer (score -1):

Before executing the code you want to log, overwrite `console.log` with one that throws it into an array (or anywhere else)

Example in ECMAScript 6:

```
var logs = [];
var oldConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function(...args) {
    logs.push(args);
    oldConsoleLog.call(this, args);
}
```

Comment: So If I want to create a button that basically takes a snapshot of the page and prints out the console, I would have to initiate this sort of thing before that event happens, correct?

Comment: Question: is not this going to get into an infinite recursive call?

Answer (score -1):

Shadow the methods you want to observe and do something with their data, e.g.

```
if (console) (function (obj, types, callback) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice, // slice used later to protect args from change
        i;
    function wrap(type, method, callback) {
        return function () {
            callback.call(this, type, slice.call(arguments), method);
            return method.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }
    for (i = 0; i < types.length; ++i)
        obj[types[i]] = wrap(types[i], obj[types[i]], callback);
}(
    console,
    ['log', 'warn', 'error'],
    function (type, args, meth) {
        // this is the callback, do something with the data
        // **don't use console here unless you want an infinite loop ;)
        alert(type);
    }
));
```

The *IIFE* here is totally generic, you can use it to shadow methods on any object you want

Here I put the callback as just alerting the type, i.e. will alert *log* if you used `console.log` then it logs to the console

```
// with callback defined above,
console.log('foo'); // alerts "log" then logs "foo"
```

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill which line gave you the error? (I can't reproduce)